# I need an alternative for "-descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale"

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I submitted my iPhone app to apple the other day, and they said I used a private API in the process "-descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale" which means i need to find an alternative to my current code which is:

```
NSString *lastSyncDate = [store.lastSync descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" timeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0] locale:nil];
```

What would be the best replacement line of code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and configure an `NSDateFormatter` to your liking, then call `-[NSDateFormatter stringFromDate:]`.